# Why can I convert an RGB image to a 17 color palette, but no fewer? (Python Pillow version 10.1.0)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-palette

The image used doesn't seem to matter. Here's an RGB image:
[image: blue/black gradient]

```py
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('sigh.png')

img_P17 = img.convert('P', palette = Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE, colors = 17) # 17 color palettized image
img_P17.show()

# Fewer than 17 color palette conversion not working for some reason:
img_P16 = img.convert('P', palette = Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE, colors = 16) # 16 color palettized image
img_P16.show() #ValueError: conversion not supported
```

[image: pil_17_color_palette_vs_16_color_palette]

Comment: Provide a minimal, reproduce-able example. (Images of code are nearly never useful.)

Comment: Kindly share your image too - Google Drive or Dropbox or Github or some such might be necessary if large or TIFF.

Comment: Here's an image and the exact same code from the other photo I posted.

Comment: Aside: I think you are missing the point @Ouroborus is making. The image of the code is definitely ***not*** exactly the same - it is neither searchable,  nor editable, nor runnable. In answer, try `print(img.mode)`.

Comment: Mode is RGB as stated in post title

Comment: Your code works fine on Pillow v10.0

Comment: I can reproduce this (Pillow 10.1.0, Python 3.12.0, macOS 14.1.1). It’s got *something* to do with the image turning from 8 to 4 bits per pixel, and the PNG saving machinery getting confused and trying to convert from "P" to "P;4" mode. Saving the image works if you just do `img_P16.save('foo.png')`, but not with `img_P16.save('foo.png', save_all=True)`. Looks like a Pillow bug to me.